# Linux: programmatically get system shutdown time?

Tags: c, linux, shutdown, uptime, sysctl

I am getting Linux uptime from file /proc/uptime. From where to get last shutdown time of machine. how to read it from wtmp file in "c". I don't want parse output of last -x command. can i get using sysctl?

Comment: What distribution and version number are you using (Ubuntu 14.04, CentOS 7, etc.)? Different init systems may write different info to wtmp.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, this kind of data is access through the `getutent` api calls. You can use `utmpname` to set the file name, and use `getutent` to get every entry in the login history.

For details of the API checkout http://linux.die.net/man/3/getutent

The format of the file is described at http://linux.die.net/man/5/utmp

EDIT

For how to get the shutdown time specifically, check the `ut_user` of the `struct utmp` returned by the API, and do something if it's `shutdown`, for example, loop through all entries in the file with this code:

```
struct utmp *u = getutent();
if (strncmp(u>ut_user, "shutdown", 8) == 0) {
    // parse the shutdown time in u->ut_time
}
```

Following code successfully identified all the shutdown entries on my system:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <utmp.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct utmp *u;
    int ret;

    ret = utmpname("/var/log/wtmp");
    if (ret < 0) {
            perror("utmpname");
            return 1;
    }
    while (true) {
            u = getutent();
            if (!u) {
                    perror("getutent");
                    break;
            }
            if (strncmp(u->ut_user, "shutdown", 8) == 0) {
                    time_t t = u->ut_time;
                    struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
                    char timestr[128];

                    strftime(timestr, sizeof timestr, "%a %b %d %T %Y", tm);
                    printf("%s: %s\n", u->ut_user, timestr);
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output on my system:

```
shutdown: Tue Mar 08 00:13:00 2016
shutdown: Sat Mar 12 08:45:57 2016
shutdown: Sat Mar 19 09:55:49 2016
shutdown: Wed Mar 23 16:24:39 2016
....
```

Comment: it don't provide shutdown time. i can get BOOT_TIME using getutent  api.

Comment: @RaviBhushan It does have shutdown time, see my post.

Comment: If condition doesn't satisfy.  i have printed "ut.ut_user" before if condition. there is no user "shutdown". i am getting user reboot, runlevel, and normal user.

Comment: @RaviBhushan maybe post your entire code? it works for me, see my code.